# Gradle sync finished.. but throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add the ImageMap lib from https://github.com/aectann/socratica-android/tree/master/libraries/image-map on Android Studio.
Here is my `app/build.gradle`

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "PACKAGE"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.socratica.mobile:image-map:1.+@aar'
    }
```

It finishes syncing successfully, and puts the library on External Libraries, but throws ***ClassNotFoundException*** when trying to refer ***com.socratica.mobile.ImageMap.***
and the layout xml file is..

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.socratica.mobile.ImageMap
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/usamap"
            app:map="@xml/usamap"
            app:selectionPadding="50dp"
            app:selectionColor="#f00"
            app:selectionType="stroke"
            app:selectionStrokeWidth="2"
            android:id="@+id/map"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: yes,Harry is right..there might be error somewhere in your xml file..please post xml code for clearer understanding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put this line on the dependencies of your `build.gradle`:

> compile project(':libraries:big-image')